# 'match' form in Racket Scheme. Question about matching sequences

Tags: scheme, racket

I am experimenting with Racket's 'match' form and would like to match sequences of items in a list.  Each item will have particular properties.  For example, if I wanted to match alternating sequences of numbers and strings corresponding (roughly) to the regular expression:

```
#rx"([0-9]+ \"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\")+"
```

The code below seems to do the job:

```
(define (match-sequence L)
  (let ([n-lst '()]     ; Used to collect numbers found.
        [s-lst '()])    ; Used to collect strings found.
    (define  (m-test L)
      (match L
             [(list-rest (? number? n) (? string? s)  ... (? m-test))
              (set! n-lst `(,@n-lst ,n))
              (set! s-lst `(,@s-lst ,(car s)))                
              (list (reverse n-lst) (reverse s-lst))]
             ['()
              #t]
             [else
             #f]))
    (m-test L)))
```

I realize that the #rx and code above don't quite match the same sequences but it is just an analogy.

**Is this the most succinct way of writing this in Racket?**

I tried patterns like:

```
(list ((? number? n) (? string? s)) ...)
```

and Racket did not accept this.

Patterns like:
    (list (? number? n) (? string? s) ...)
require the first item of the list being matched to be numeric and all others to be strings.

I tried quasiquotation and splicing in several ways with no success.

There must be a more elegant formation but I can't seem to find it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It *looks* like you're trying to separate numbers from the rest, which is not that difficult:

```
(define (match-sequence L)
  (match L
    [(list* (? number? n) (? string? s) ... rest)
     (let ([r (match-sequence rest)])
       (list `(,n ,@(car r)) `(,@s ,@(cadr r))))]
    ['() '(() ())]))
```

but in that case, you could just use [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._filter%29%29), or even better, [`partition`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/list..rkt%29._partition%29%29):

```
(partition number? '(1 "a" "b" 2 3 "c" "d" 4))
```

But maybe you want to group together the string subsequences, where the above code is closer:

```
(define (match-sequence L)
  (match L
    [(list* (? number? n) (? string? s) ... rest)
     (let ([r (match-sequence rest)])
       (list `(,n ,@(car r)) `(,s ,@(cadr r))))]
    ['() '(() ())]))
```

and in that case it's easier to go with multiple values instead of making up a list wrapper:

```
(define (match-sequence L)
  (match L
    [(list* (? number? n) (? string? s) ... rest)
     (let-values ([(ns ss) (match-sequence rest)])
       (values `(,n ,@ns) `(,s ,@ss)))]
    ['() (values '() '())]))
```

Comment: Thank you.  The final `match-sequence` is what I was after.  The actual sequencing/ordering of items was important so partition would not have worked.  The example was simplified just for the purpose of asking the question.  The actual application was converting HTML sequences of the form: _text_ `<input type="radio" ...>` _text_ `<input type="radio" ..>` _etc._ in to a Docbook `<orderedlist>` so the intent would have been obscured by the actual code.  It probably would have been better to use `read-html` etc. but the code I have now is fine.

Comment: Hopefully, `match` will eventually support direct expression of what this is doing -- the underlying implementation is already flexible enough.